# Why is the output False if -8 & 7 is not 0?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Why is the output False if -8 & 7 is not 0?
 I know its supposed to be && but the question says "Is there a problem in the code? What is it? And why is the output False?" can someone help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    if (-8 & 7) 
    {
        printf("Always\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convert -8 and 7 into bits and perform bitwise AND masking, you will get 0000, decimal Zero

Comment: You put (-8 && 7) for logical AND operation

Comment: `I know its supposed to be &&`...how?

Comment: @Lundin: Statements addressing a person’s knowledge, as in “If you understand…,” unnecessarily address a person rather than subject matter and may be perceived as unkind. Such phrasing suggests the OP ought to have knowledge they may not have been taught yet and therefore has neglected some duty.

Comment: @VivekBhardwaj: The question states the OP knows that `&&` was the originally intended operator but that they are deliberately asking about `&`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Decent schools teach binary and hex before you are allowed to write a single line of code. If they don't, then that's the problem of the teacher and then they are the one who should be answering this question. I would expect schools to teach binary and hex far earlier than they teach the bit-wise operators, because teaching it the other way around would be very stupid.

Comment: @Lundin: Regardless of what schools should or should not do, addressing a person’s knowledge in the way you did may be perceived as unkind and rude. Please avoid it.

Comment: The answer is already given in the above comment.

Comment: what  bitwise AND means?. searched the whole internet cant seem to understand something. we were taught binary but this question requires us to ask for help on the internet cause we were not taught bit wise operators.

Comment: @EricPostpischil exactly

Answer (score 5):

> *Why is the output False if -8 & 7 is not 0?*

A: It **is** 0, actually.

To elaborate, `&` is the bit-wise AND operator, and you need to check for the binary representation of the arguments.

Considering [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation,

- `-8` has a representation `1111111111111000`
- `7` has a representation `0000000000000111`

According to the rule of bitwise AND, the produced result is `0`, which evaluates to FALSY. So, in your case, the `if-else` condition boils down to

```
if (0)                     // this is FALSE 
{
    printf("Always\n");
}
else                       // else block gets executed
{
    printf("False\n");     // so this is printed
}
```

That's why, the `else` block is executed and you see `False` being printed out.

Comment: While two’s complement is the overwhelming representation in modern systems, it is not required by the standard, so one cannot assert that 1…1000 **is** the representation of −8 without including this implementation-dependent assumption.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah we must absolutely teach newbies about fictional one's complement and signed magnitude computers.

Comment: @Lundin: We should teach newbies about deriving correct results from specifications. The fact that some old machines and implementations used one’s complement is less important than teaching that one constructs correct code by deriving behavior from specifications.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes we should absolutely teach newbies to read and consider the specification ISO 9899:2018 chapter 6.2.6.2. And then thoughtfully consider that `int` may have padding bits, negative zeroes and trap representations. This must be done during the first week in a beginner class.

Comment: @Lundin: One does not need to lay out all the history and alternatives while explaining at a level like this. A simple note that an assumption has been made suffices both to be correct and to illustrate correct reasoning from specifications.